# Angular 8 prevent sharing session between browser tabs on duplicating tabs

Tags: javascript, angular, session, local-storage

I read blogs on session storage and local storage. Now as per my understanding

**Session Storage** : The session Storage exists only within the current browser tab. Another tab with the same page will have a different session storage.

**Local Storage** : Data is shared between all tabs and windows from the same origin.

Now my requirement is whenever user opens a new tab or duplicate a previously opened tab in same window I can see session storage have some value. If user open a new tab or duplicate the currently opened tab I want my session storage to be empty and generate a new session key .But if user refresh or reload page I want to continue with same session Storage.

Note : I am not sharing session in my code, neither I am storing anything from local storage to session storage. Any idea how can I achieve above scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a hash when your application load and save keys with this hash in your localStorage ?

The app.component.ts `construct()` will fire only when you load for the first time. You can get the browser tabId with `window.tabId`

Comment: but how I will get to know that applcation loads in new tab, by storing hash in local storage

Comment: Also what if i refresh My page ,it will still load app component.ts

Comment: but with same tabId ;)

Comment: window.tabId is not a prpoperty in angular.can you be please more specifc How i can get tabID